# Kubernetes/Minikube: After mounting volume, pod mounted directory is empty

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I am new to k8s. I am following [official tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) on setting up Nginx pods in k8s using minikube, mounting a volume and serving index.html.

When I mount and go to hompe page, i receive this error that 
`directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden`.

If I dont mount anything, i receive a "Welcome to Nginx" page.

This is the content of that folder before mount. And after mount is empty

```
root@00c1:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 494 Jul 23 11:45 50x.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 612 Jul 23 11:45 index.html
```

Why is mounted folder inside pod empty after mounting?

This is my setup

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/my_username/test/html"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-hello-rc
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-nginx-tester
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
      containers:
        - name: task-pv-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: "http-server"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
              name: task-pv-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-tester
  labels:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 30500
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
```

Any info would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your configuration on my running k8s environment. After some adjustments the following manifest works smoothly for me:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/my_username/test/html"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Mi
  volumeName: task-pv-volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-hello-rc
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-nginx-tester
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
      containers:
        - name: task-pv-container
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: "http-server"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
              name: task-pv-volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-tester
  labels:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 30500
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello-nginx-tester
```

Comment: Hmm, i tried this code but still receiving the same error. Are you using minikube? I searched into it and the reason why i am receiving this error is because i need to mount volumes to minikube first and then those will be transferred to k8s. I will post the solution later

Comment: I've checked it via `kubeadm` .

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the directory "/usr/share/nginx/html" will be 1000 because you have set the SecurityContext fsGroup values. Hence you have unable to access the directory.  if you remove the SecurityContext section, the owner of the mounted volume will be set as root. You won't get access issues.

Comment: Its not that, removed the directive, rebuild minicube just to be sure but it still the same. If I dont mount anything it will work fine, if I mound that folder becomes empty